# Disk size shows the same after cloning a small disk to a larger disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clone, clonezilla

I am running Windows 10 Pro and I cloned (disk-to-disk) my 120GB SSD drive to a larger 2TB SATA drive because I was running out of disk space on the 120GB. I used Clonezilla and everything finished successfully.

After cloning, I removed the 120GB SSD drive and booted from the 2TB SATA drive Windows loaded successfully, but in File Explorer, it show that the `C:` drive is still 120GB and the new 2TB is not shown.

In Disk Management however, the new drive is shown with 4 partitions: 100MB System Reserved, 120GB (`C:`), 450MB Recovery Partition and 1751GB Unallocated.

How can I increase the size of Drive `C:`?

Comment: @Damon - FYI, your link is bad. It has an extra "/ added to the end of it.

Comment: Since cloning does write the partition sector-by-sector to new disk, it also writes the old size. You can expand your partition in Disk Management Console to allocate the entire drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remaining GB (difference between 120gb and 2TB) of your hard drive are free and must be manually assigned to a new partition or assigned to drive C (Resize the partition)

You can do it manually. In Windows, go to Computer Management and Extend disk space. If you do not want to do it manually you can use applications like [AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard](http://www.disk-partition.com/download-home.html), [GParted](https://gparted.org/), etc.

[HowTO resize partition or create a new partition with AOMEI](http://www.disk-partition.com/help/resize-partition.html)

Comment: The extend volume menu is disabled. Maybe it's because I have the 450MB Recovery partition at the right side of (C:). How can I move this so that drive C and the un-allocated are beside each other

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not specific to Windows or Clonezilla. What happened is Clonezilla does not purely copy files, but copies partitions as clearly stated on [the official Clonezilla page](http://clonezilla.org):

> “Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program…”

So what happened is when you ran Clonezilla between the 120GB drive and the 2TB drive is Clonezilla literally copied the exact 120GB partition from your old drive to the new drive. This is very useful for doing disk imaging from one drive of the same exact size to another drive of the same size but—as you now can see—is not so great when copying data from a small drive to a larger drive.

So your choice now is to create a new partition with the extra space on the 2TB drive and use that. But if I were you, I would reformat and repartition that 2TB and use a pure file copying utility. I’m no Windows expert, but based on [this PC World magazine article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2086644/how-to-upgrade-to-a-larger-hard-drive.html), [EaseUS Todo Backup Free 9.2](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm) seems to be a better tool for copying purely files from one drive to another.

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla does a straight copy duplicating partition sizes by default. This means that if you copy from a small disk to a large disk, you will get the same partitions and their sizes of the small disk on the large disk with the additional space on the large disk as unallocated space.

If you are lucky and the smaller disk does not have another partition after the file space partition and what follows is just unallocated space, you could use a disk manager application to just make the file system partition larger and use up the unallocated space

This first option may require you to use two utilities, one to extend the file system partition into the unallocated space and the other to modify the file system so that the new space is available. For example with Ubuntu Linux when I ran into this problem, I had to use the `parted` utility to extend the file space partition and then the `resizepart` utility to properly resize the Linux file system.

However, Clonezilla has the option of doing a proportional copy. I used this option when I ran into the problem of same partition size when doing a disk to disk copy to a larger drive on a Windows 10 PC, in my case a 32 GB eMMc to a 128 GB SSD. My problem was that after the file space partition of some 30 GB there was a smaller 100 MB partition for recovery. So when I did the disk to disk copy and ran into this problem, I was not able to just extend the file space partition.

See this Clonezilla page, [The advanced parameters for disk cloning](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone/advanced/05-advanced-param.php)

> If the target disk size is larger than the source disk, you can try to
> use option "-k1" which will create the partition table proportionally
> in the target disk and turn on option "-r" to resize the file file
> system in the partition automatically. This is useful to make use all
> of the target disk size.